# Prestashop 1.7:Which hook to use when Order is FREE (no payment)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, prestashop-helper-classes

I need help in a case, where the order total price is zero(using coupon or product with zero value)

Which hook will trigger when the Free order is being placed.

Or Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

I would definitely use **actionValidateOrder**

There you can check $params inside the hook which
contains the order/cart that had just been made.

If **$params['order']->total_paid == 0** you can trigger your custom code.

Comment: thanks, yes I have modified the code and added the condition.

Comment: Isn’t this `total_paid` the amount paid by the customer rather than the total price of the order?

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated hook for this.

But you can check the controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php checkFreeOrder method.